# SELECT * FROM table1, table2, table3

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I have a problem ...
In table1 I have an id, I have to compare that id in table2, then fetch the second id that is in table2 and compare it to table3 and get as a result a datum.
Example

```
TABLE1
ID   NAME ECC...
1      Jhon
2      Frank

TABLE2
ID ID2 ECC..
1   4
2   8

TABLE3
ID NAME
4    Sea
8    Hello
```

If I look for id 1, the result must be Sea
If I look for id 2 the result must be Hello

Thanks!

Comment: you tagged 3 different flavors of SQL... which is it? The answer is a `INNER JOIN`... just research this

Comment: So? Join them together, it's not hard.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: This question's causing a lot of friction. Plus, the RDBMS is unknown. MySQL and MSSQL are two different animals; you should tag accordingly. There's also no "php" here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use *joins*.

Your query will look like :

```
SELECT t3.name
FROM table3 t3
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t3.id = t2.id2
LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON t2.id2 = t1.id
WHERE t1.id = <your_number>
```

Comment: Thanks!! Very functional method!!

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT Table3.NAME
   FROM Table1
  INNER JOIN Table2
 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
  INNER JOIN Table3
 ON Table3.ID = Table2.ID2
  WHERE Table1.ID = 1  -- Your Search here
```

Answer (score -1):

Query:

```
 SELECT a.name As Name FROM table3 a JOIN 
 (SELECT b.id2 AS id FROM table1 a JOIN table2 b ON a.id = b.id)b
 ON a.id = b.id where b.id = <your id number (1,2) Anything>
```

Comment: a very odd way to approach this....

Comment: It approach is much better than to join 3 table in a query.

Comment: Why is it better? And you are joining 3 tables.

Comment: you are saying your subquery has benefits over explicit joins? Please, explain... I'm sure we'd all be interested in hearing your arguements

Comment: As per my view it would be the faster than explicit joins.

Comment: Your "view" is wrong.

Comment: @Gauravk subselects are rarely a better approach than joins, normally they're a lot less efficient; and a lot less readable in this case too

Comment: Ok got it, Thanks scsimon , @Mark Baker

Answer (score -1):

```
select Table2.Id,Table3.Name from Table1 inner join Table2 on Table2.ID2 = Table3.Id
```

Comment: You're missing a join on Table3. This query will fail.

Comment: sorry
select Table2.Id,Table3.Name from Table2 inner join Table3 on Table2.ID2 = Table3.Id 
try this

Answer (score -2):

Should be something like this:

```
select table3.name as name3
from table3
where table3.ID = table2.ID2
and table2.ID = table1.ID
and table1.ID = <YOURNUMBERHERE>
```

Comment: you're missing a few joins here....

Comment: @scsimon doing some implicit joins with where-and combinations, one can also perform this with LEFT JOIN and so on, but it wrote it out of my head, so no joins ;) But you are right, JOIN would be the best way

Comment: No, there are no implicit joins here, `table2` and `table1` are not mentioned in the `from` clause